# How to find out how much space workspace and build artifacts take on CloudBees Jenkins

Tags: cloudbees

Is there any way to see how much space workspace and build artifacts take on Jenkins in CloudBees dev@cloud?

When my account runs out of quota, I get a message that tells how much disk space is spent and subtracting my Forge usage from that tells me how much Jenkins takes space, but I don't know how to pinpoint which job's workspace and/or build artifacts take up the space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install the [Disk Usage plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Disk+Usage+Plugin) which will break down which builds are using the most space. Your workspace is not counted against your quota, only builds.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in CloudBees Jenkins. I can install the plugin, but it shows just "-" in the Builds and Workspace columns :(

Comment: It will run every 360 minutes, just wait a bit.

Comment: I've been waiting for several days, and doesn't still work :(

Comment: Please raise a ticket at support.cloudbees.com in that case.

Comment: FWIW - The plugin doesn't monitor all disk usage - and so you can end up in the situation where it reports less usage than the CloudBees platform detects. If this becomes problematic; contact support and we'll help resolve the issue.

Comment: Seems like Disk Usage plugin doesn't deal with artifacts produced by a job, making it rather useless in our environment. Would be nice if it had an option to monitor free space remaining on a drive.

Comment: My last comment was incorrect, I had just installed the plugin and it had not populated all the data yet. It monitors all space usage in the workspace of each job, so as long as artifacts are in the workspace they will be included in the calculations.